# Calling Superclass method in python subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm new to Python, I have read many examples on the net to invoke superclass method subclass but none of them worked for me please find the package structure I have

```
F (director)
---1. __init__.py 
---2.A.py
---3.B.py
```

Contents are as follows

1__init__.py

```
is empty
```

2.A.py

```
class A:

 def hi(self,name):
   print ("hi",name)
```

3.B.py

```
from F.A import A
class B(A):

 def testhi(self,name):
    super().hi(name)
    super(B,self).hi(name)
    super(self).hi(name)
    A.hi(self,name)

x= B()
x.testhi("python")
```

None of them worked I always got the error message `'super' object has no attribute 'hi'`

Comment: Something else is going on that you're not showing us. Most of your attempts to call the superclass method would work fine. (`super(self).hi(name)` is wrong, though.)

Comment: (1) Repair indentation of shown code. (2) Check if you imported the right `A`. E.g. try `print(A.hi)` in `B.py` directly after importing `A`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher fixing the indentation resolved the issue. posted the answer, so that, it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: fixed the indentation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MichaelButscher the method hi was at the same level as the class A, causing it to be not a class instance-level method. Fixing this resolved the issue.